# Why I can't share variables between my child/parent components in my Angular 8 application?

Tags: angular, typescript

Before asking this question, I spent 3 days trying to figure out a way of sharing a variable between my components in Angular. I am completely new to this frontend world, so I just wanted to get this thing done.

Anyways, my app.commponent.ts like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Event} from '@angular/router';
import {DataService} from './data.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 title = 'app works!';
 count: number;
 clientId: number;
 name = '';

 constructor(private titleService: Title, router: Router, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public data: DataService) {
   router.events.subscribe(event => {
     if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       const title = this.getTitle(router.routerState, router.routerState.root).join(' | ');
       titleService.setTitle(title);
     }
   });
 }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.clientId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 600000)  + 1);
   console.log('client from app: ' + this.clientId);
   this.data.currentMessageSubscriber.subscribe((data: any) => {
     this.name = data.msg;
   })
 }
```

My form.component.ts is like that:

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from '../service/data.service';
import FiiData from './FiiData';
import FiiTax from './FiiTax';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.scss'],
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
  public pageData;
  clientId: number;

      @Input() name: string;

    constructor(router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private httpClient: HttpClient, public data: DataService) {
      console.log('from from: ');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.pageData = <any>this.route.snapshot.data;

      console.log(this.pageData.title);
      console.log('from from: ');
      this.data.notify({msg : 'hello'});
      console.log(this.name);


  }
```

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  public currentMessageSubscriber = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }


  public notify(message: any) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }
}
```

I have tried creating a service to share this variable, but I always get null when printing the variable in the console from the form.componet.

I also tried using Observable in the service, as well as @Imput, but nothing works in this project.

I am using Angular 8. I am about to give out...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to just share your data from one component to another?

Comment: Yes, I just want to store a variable in the app.component.ts so it can be accessed from other components. It seems like the variable from the service is never updated, no matter how many times I call it `exchangeMsg()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your implementation.

Firstly you are declaring clientId of type `Subject` but assigning it a `BehaviorSubject` at this line in your service.ts

```
public clientId: Subject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);
```

You should do like this

```
public clientId: Subject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);
```

Secondly please note that whenever you want new value from your `BehaviorSubject` source observable so first you have to pass any value into it like this

```
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
public currentMessageSubscriber = this.messageSource.asObservable();


exchangeMsg(message: any) {
 this.messageSource.next(message)
}
```

Then in your `app.component.ts` you should do like this

```
this.dataService.exchangeMsg({msg : 'hello'})
```

And inside your `form.component.ts` you can `subscribe` to source `Observable` like this

```
constructor(private __dataService : DataService){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.__dataService.currentMessageSubscriber .subscribe((data : any)=>{
   console.log(data) // output : {msg : 'hello'}
  }) 
}
```

Thirdly, you are receiving `null` each time you are subscribing to your source `Observable` because you are not pushing any value into that `Observable` and you are just subscribing it so each time it will display you the default value which you provided `null`

Comment: Fahad, I tried implementing as you said, but I always get null when printing the variable from.component. I guess my app structure is somehow preventing me from doing that... Thanks!

Comment: can you update your code in post what have you tried yet?

Comment: Fahad, I added the code here: [https://gist.github.com/jaimedantas/fcd7ce9f5dabb4aeb93b1fe2afcece2b]

Comment: I created a basic example for you at here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4l3wf

Comment: Fahad, I added it [here](https://gist.github.com/jaimedantas/fcd7ce9f5dabb4aeb93b1fe2afcece2b)

Comment: Did you check my example?

Comment: Yes, I implemented, and I am still getting undefined when I print from form  `console.log(this.name);`

Comment: update your complete code in your question then i will tell you what's wrong

Comment: Actualy, your are logging wrong. You are sending data from `form.component.ts` using `notify` function and you are not logging in `app.component.ts`

Comment: I solved by using `localStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify(content));`. Thank you for your support Fahad.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved with the redux pattern.

Redux has Store that saved data then it can be use any components.

angular can use the redux pattern with ngrx.

this is the ngrx api docs.

https://ngrx.io/docs

hope it will helps(sry about my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply share data like below

//Shared Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  myShareVar = 'Test';

  constructor() { }

}
```

//Component- 1

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../myShared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  template: `
  <b>component1</b>
<p>Shared Service Data <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="sharedService.myShareVar"></p>`,
  styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public sharedService: SharedService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

//Component - 2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../myShared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component2',
  template: `
  <b>component2</b>
<p>Shared Service Data <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="sharedService.myShareVar"></p>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css']
})
export class Component2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public sharedService: SharedService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Working Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/sameer-shared-data-between-components

Comment: Thanks for helping Sameer, but I've tried that way and the value is never updated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using a service with cache storage like that:

```
export class DataService {

  private clientId: number;

  public store(content: number) {
    localStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify(content));
  }


  public retrieve() {
    return localStorage.getItem('id');
  }

}
```